# git - rollback pushes to specific commit

Tags: git, github

I have pushed few commits on a remote branch, but realized that I made mistake and would like to roll back all changes to a particular point.

example

```
- pushed commit
- pushed commit
- pushed commit
- pushed commit
- point to which i want to return
- older commits ...
```

My question is, is it possible to rollback all the changes and revert this branch to that point ?

**On the suggested topic i found part of the answer,

please tell me if i i reverse current branch to the commit i want to return to, and the i force push it. Will this accomplish a rollback ?**

Answer (score -1):

Simple as that:

```
git reset b9563df
```

Just replace 'b9563df' with your commit code

Comment: soo.... if i use commit code of the "point to which i want to return" it will go back to this point removing all commits i have pushed after that one ?

Comment: @AdrianReszka No, it will do nothing of the sort. This command doesn't affect your remote branch.